# How can this question be made clearer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94496/52541) was closed as "Unclear what you are asking". The question itself seems pretty clear to me. The OP wants to know why Eddard had to take Arya with him to King's Landing. Sansa's case is clear as she was betrothed to the Crown Prince and it would have helped her to know him better if she lived close enough and she'd also be able to learn about her duties as the future Queen by living at the Court. Arya's case can understandably elude some viewers. The already-existing answers are pretty good too.

As stated already, it seems clear enough to me as it is but in case that I am wrong, how can we make it clearer?

Comment: Not a fan of this question but seems pretty clear to me so posting my reopen vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a question closed as unclear and it seems pretty clear to you, then feel free to edit it to reflect so. This is what edits are for. Seems like you've explained the question in your post so why not edit it into that question.

However, there is one more thing. The question in the end `Shouldn't she better stay home with her mother?` may make the question opinion-based. So, this part must be fixed.

The question seemed unclear to me, but I waited for community's response and then I did cast my vote.

Comment: FWIW the question seems fine to me as it stands, it could _maybe_ do with some more explanation but that wouldn't necessarily make it clearer. And whilst the end question could be construed as POB it's essentially asking the title question but in reverse... it's wording is just slightly unfortunate.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot anyways after update I think everyone will be fine with it and also reopened now